# How can I present a modal View Controller with the default segue animation of dismissing one?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

In my App I display a wizard the first time the app runs. At the end of the wizard it segues to the main screen. The default animation for this is that the main screen slides in from the bottom. However, I want the wizard view controller to slide down to reveal the main screen using the same animation as when a modal view controller is dismissed.
Is there a way to achieve this? Do I have to implement a custom segue for this or can I somehow use the animation style of dismissing a view controller?

Comment: Why is the wizard not a presented view controller and the main screen the window root view controller?

Comment: Because I can't present it before the main screen did appear, so the user can see the main screen for a short time..

Comment: Unless you set the alpha for the main screen to 0 or simply hide it in your viewWillAppear.

Comment: I've tried both, setting the alpha to 0 or hiding it. Unfortunately it now shows a red screen for a short time

Answer (score 0):

Show your Main Screen with the Wizard screen on top of it (displayed as a modal) and then, when the user dismisses the Wizard, it will slide down and show the Main Screen.

Comment: I tried this, but I can't display it as modal without showing the main screen for a short time. I can't present the wizard before "viewDidAppear" has been called on the main screen

Comment: Why not? Present it in -viewDidLoad method (without animations). It should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. The view controller will not be presented and the following warning is logged: Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x1d88b3e0> on <YOInitViewController: 0x1cd88880> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: and if you present on viewWillAppear?